# Страницы грузятся по 3-4 секунды (денвер)

Tags: denwer

Не знаю после какого момента, на компе стали грузиться страницы по 3-4 секунды, крутящиеся на денвере. Невозможно работать. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно попробовать сделать?

Comment: Если вам не важно, какой должен быть веб-сервер, то для разработки и отладки ваших веб-приложений используйте обычный Apache, при этом загрузив и установив XAMPP, в котором уже все настроено: pma, perl, php, mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант номер раз - переустановить Denwer (сохранить рабочий материал из папки **home**, снять дамп базы, [деинсталлировать денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/other.html#h30-19), установить заново)
Вариант номер два - использовать какой-нибудь другой локальный сервер, например [Winginx](http://winginx.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте сам сайт. У меня такое было, когда страница пыталась подключиться к несуществующему файлу.
(В Google Chrome - "Просмотр кода элемента" - вкладка "Networks"/ Там показывается что сколько грузится.)